# What's the name of a lexeme's "surface form"?

Tags: syntax, terminology

Phonemes are realized through phones, morphemes are realized with morphs. What is the corresponding word for a lexeme? A casual google search isn't telling me much.

Comment: There are several options, usually called "words", which is not a very well-defined term. Matthews' _Morphology_ describes three common meanings of "word"; one of them is `Lexeme` (the other two are `Word-form` and `Phonological Word`). [Here's a diagram of how it works](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf) with the English verbs _lie_.

Comment: They are usually called word forms (of a lexeme).

Comment: They could also be called **allolexes**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **`LEXEME`** (also **`LEXICAL ITEM`**, depending on your framework) is, indeed, what you have in mind (the [*emic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emic_unit) unit) then **`LEX`** *could* be its counterpart (the *etic* unit), with the other realizations being its **`ALLOLEXES`** (as pointed out by [curiousdannii](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/2555/curiousdannii)). Nevertheless, I have seldom seen either of the two terms used in English: you will find them neither in Trask's *Dictionary of Grammatical Terms* (1996), for example, nor in Crystal's *The Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language* (1997, second edition) or his *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics* (2008, sixth edition) or Strazny's *Encyclopedia of Linguistics* (2005) or Malmkjær's *The Routledge Linguistics Encyclopedia* (2010, third edition), and you will find merely a single mention of *allolex* in Collinge's *An Encyclopaedia of Language* (2005) and just a few more in Brown's *The Encyclopedia of Language and Linguistics* (2005, second edition), although their equivalents certainly do occur, for example, in German and Czech linguistic texts more frequently as far as I am aware.

An example of terminological divergence, probably stemming from different linguistic tradition/framework, can be seen in the following quotation from an article by [Joachim Mugdan](http://www.uni-muenster.de/Sprachwiss/en/Mitarbeiter/Lehrbeauftragte/Mugdan/) of the University of Münster, Germany, *Units of word-formation* (currently in press, available [here as a PDF manuscript](http://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/allgemeine_sprachwissenschaft/dozenten-unterlagen/mugdan/hsk_16_mugdan_finalversion_k.pdf)  (p. 19, all emphasis mine):

> *A **lexeme** is a set of **grammatical words** which have the same content, save for their morphosyntactic properties. While grammatical words are linguistic signs, a characterization of lexemes as signs (cf. Aronoff 1994: 9; Montermini 2010: 86) deprives this term of its meaning. Occasionally, a **grammatical word** is called **lex** or, in relation to the lexeme it belongs to, **allolex** (in analogy to allomorph, see section 2.3.).*

Although the term *`grammatical word`* *has* sometimes been used instead, I find it rather confusing, because it can also refer to words having a grammatical function (i.e. *function* words) rather than lexical content (i.e. *content* words). I myself prefer the term *`morphological word`*, or rather **`MORPHOSYNTACTIC WORD`**, to emphasize its syntactic/*syntagmatic* dimension, as opposed to the concepts of *`phonological word`* and *`orthographical word`*,  with which it can, but does not have to, coincide in different languages. Nonetheless, I would definitely recommend the term **`WORD-FORM`**, suggested by [jlawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/482/jlawler) and [Alex B.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/445/alex-b) in their comments, as it appears to be far more frequent in the literature and is thus preferable.

Answer (score 0):

**Inscription** I'd generally say. You ask for a surface name, so it depends which surface: on the phonological surface, there's these inscriptions or **morphemes**, which then go to become phones as you said. On the other, the meaning surface, the inscriptions are interpreted as morphemes or morphemes' **features**, I guess.